# Django - configure database on launch

Tags: django, security

For security reasons, I do not want to have all my database information stored in plaintext in settings.py. I would like to load the information into the memory (ie - set the DATABASE setup var) when the Django server starts.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I think there is a misunderstanding here. The idea is compartmentalize security. If an attacker successfully gains access to the django machine, I do not want them to be able to access the database (on a different machine). This is not unreasonable. Obviously, when the machine restarts, the information would have to be put in again - but that is the cost of complete compartmentalization. With this approach, a breach of the django server machine would have no impact on the security of the data.

Comment: In this case don't you have this database information available somewhere in plain text as well (just in a different file, say your webserver config)? I don't think there is a security concern as long you don't share the information with the wrong people.

Comment: See edit. I do not want to keep the information anywhere at all - I want to manually put it in when the server starts.

Comment: Ok. The problem you are facing is that it is not that simple to pass these kind of extra options to your webserver (apache, nginx) on startup. Honestly I don't see a real way to achieve this without some complicated solution.

Comment: How about creating a file that holds the database information, and then setting the settings + deleting the file on startup? This was my initial thought, but as far as I can tell, Django has no signals or anything for startup...

Comment: Something like this is possible, but you can not just delete the new file easily afterwards. Lets say you create a new settings file which should be handled by the django appilcation. This one set the database settings. Once you delete it afterwards where can Django access the information. I am not that into the Django code, so it makes a lot of cycles forth and back the settings to get the database related information.

Comment: Ah, so you mean to say that when I set my settings, they are not actually loaded into the memory (or rather - they need to be reloaded repeatedly)

Comment: No, they are in memory. But What if the server reboots? What on machine reboot? Also when running Django on a production environment you run it in multiple worker processes. How do you know how exactly the web server is handling these workers? Are they loading one Django instance per worker, etc.? There are just too many uncertainties to go that way.

Answer (score -1):

You can move the database settings to another file but what do you gain? The details would need to be stored somewhere: the server can't load the details into memory and then delete the file from which it read the details because then it won't be able to connect to the database the next time it restarts.

It would also needlessly complicate your system because your system has already been compromised when someone can read the source. You should worry more about that than moving all passwords (and similar details, such as API keys) into special files elsewhere.

Comment: See edit -  I do not want to keep the information anywhere at all - I want to manually put it in when the server starts.